# Char buffer for serial input: char str[2] vs char* str = (char*) malloc(2)

Tags: serial, softwareserial

I am using software serials on my Arduino nano to read data from my esp01 in functionality testing for the software serial. I simply make the esp01 to send a string "OK" to an Arduino's software rx serial port (in this case pin 9) , and then the Arduino prints it on the monitor via its hardware serial (USB).

I've found that when I allocate space for the string in Arduino using `char str[2]`, the message seems to be correct. However, with `char* str = (char*)malloc(2)`, there appear to be an unkown character tai
ling the string "OK"

Below is the code I use

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>


SoftwareSerial s(9,10);
void setup() {
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  s.begin(9600);      // link to esp01
}

void loop() {
  
  if(s.available() > 0){
    char txt[2];
    int indx = 0;

   // read input
    while(s.available() > 0 && indx <=SIZE-1){
        char buff;
        buff=  s.read();
        txt[indx] =  buff;
        Serial.println(indx);
        indx++;
     
    }
   // bink an LED for debugging
   if((String)txt == "OK"){
    digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(2,LOW);
    delay(500);
   }

   //reset index
   if(indx ==2){
     
     Serial.println(txt);
     Serial.print("Size of string:");
     Serial.println(sizeof(txt));
    indx = 0;
   }
  } // if(s.available())
  
}
```

here is the print-out of the serial monitor

[image]

That tailing square is the myster for me.

Any help would be grateful!!

Boris

Comment: To store two characters you need three slots in the array.  You forgot about the null terminator to mark the end of the string.  So depending on where the array is in memory there may or may not be extra junk behind it that gets printed because the string isn’t terminated.

Comment: you need 3 positions. 'O 'K' '\0'

Comment: Re “`while(s.available() > 0 && indx <=SIZE-1)`”: where did you define `SIZE`?

Answer (score 1):

First, a few general notes:

- The difference between `char str[2]` and
  `char* str = (char*) malloc(2)` is irrelevant to you problem. It
  changes the place where the array is stored, the meaning of
  `sizeof str`, and `malloc()` will blow up your RAM if you call it
  repeatedly and forget to `free()`.
- In your code, `sizeof(txt)` is the constant `2`: the actual size in
  bytes of the array `txt`, irrespective of how much relevant data it
  holds.
- You want `txt` and `indx`to remember their contents across calls to
  `loop()`. You should either make them global or qualify them as
  `static`.
- Avoid the `String` class if at all possible. Here, since you use it
  only to compare two strings, you can use the traditional
  [`strcmp()`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__string.html#ga46f3cbd2de457c0fb340a1f379fc33ba) function instead.

Now, the bulk of my answer is just about expanding on what has already
been said about properly terminating strings.

A string is a variable-length list of characters. Whenever you are
dealing with a list that has a variable length, you need to somehow keep
track of this length. There are two common ways to do so:

1. either you store the length in a variable,
2. or you put a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) (a value that would be invalid within
   the list) after the last element to mark the end of the list.

Both methods are valid, and I am going to illustrate both of them below.
However, in the case of strings, the C++ language uses method 2,
with the ASCII “NUL” character (numeric value 0) as a sentinel.

**Method 1**:

```cpp
void loop() {
  static char txt[2];
  static size_t indx = 0;

  while (s.available()) {
    // read input
    char c = s.read();
    txt[indx++] = c;

    // report
    Serial.print("Received: '");
    Serial.print(c);
    Serial.print("', string: \"");
    Serial.write(txt, indx);
    Serial.print("\", size: ");
    Serial.println(indx);
    if (indx == 2 && memcmp(txt, "OK", 2) == 0) {
      Serial.println("Correct message");
    }

    // reset index
    if (indx >= sizeof txt) {
      indx = 0;
    }
  } // if(s.available())
}
```

Some things to note:

- The `indx` variable holds the length of the string. It also happens to
  be the index of the next available cell in the `txt` array, if any.
- The string is printed using the
  `write(const char *buffer, size_t size)` method, which accepts a size
  as a second argument. Unlike `print(const char *)`, it doesn't depend
  on the string being NUL-terminated.
- In order to check that we received “OK”, we have to check for both the
  correct length (`indx == 2`) and correct contents. The contents is
  checked using the `memcmp()` function, which can compare arbitrary
  byte arrays and, again, does not depend on NUL-termination.
- An important loop invariant here is `idx < sizeof txt`. It is true at
  initialization and is restored by the “reset index” section at the end
  of the loop. The “read input” section depends on this invariant to not
  overflow the buffer.

**Method 2**:

```cpp
void loop() {
  static char txt[3];
  static size_t indx = 0;

  while (s.available()) {
    // read input
    char c = s.read();
    txt[indx++] = c;
    txt[indx] = '\0';

    // report
    Serial.print("Received: '");
    Serial.print(c);
    Serial.print("', string: \"");
    Serial.print(txt);
    Serial.print("\", size: ");
    Serial.println(indx);
    if (strcmp(txt, "OK") == 0) {
      Serial.println("Correct message");
    }

    // reset index
    if (indx >= sizeof txt - 1) {
      indx = 0;
      txt[indx] = '\0';
    }
  } // if(s.available())
}
```

Again, some notes:

- This is actually an hybrid of methods 1 and 2, as the `indx` variable
  is still used to keep track of where to insert the next incoming
  character. This just happens to be more convenient and efficient than
  putting that character into its own length-1 string and using
  `strcat()`.
- The array is now one cell longer, to make room for the terminating
  NUL.
- There is another loop invariant now: correct string termination
  (`txt[indx] == '\0'`). This invariant has to be enforced both on
  reading and on resetting.
- The string being NUL-terminated, it can now be printed with `print()`
  and compared with `strcmp()`. The string literal `"OK"` is guaranteed
  to be NUL-terminated by the compiler.

This second method is generally safer because there are a lot of
functions and methods in Arduino and C++ that expect strings to be
NUL-terminated. If your strings are not, you have to be extra careful to
not use any of these string-oriented functions.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, C strings are null-terminated. So to hold 2 characters of content you need a 3-byte array. Your code that reads the chacters into the buffer also needs to be changed. (That code isn't adding the required terminating null.)

You should probably rewrite your code to use the `strncat()` function.